# Please Help me.Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

Why cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
>       at barm/btn1_clickHandler()[C:\Users\Android\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\barm\src\barm.mxml:32]
>       at barm/__btn1_click()[C:\Users\Android\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\barm\src\barm.mxml:65]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
xmlns:service="services.service.*"
                   >
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import com.adobe.serializers.utility.TypeUtility;
        import flash.sampler.DeleteObjectSample;    
        import flashx.textLayout.operations.DeleteTextOperation;
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;
        [Bindable]
        private var positionChoose:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
        protected function btn1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            GetStrDataResult.token = service.GetStrData(
    "SELECT PositionCode,LocalDesc FROM StaffPosition 
    WHERE LocalDesc IN ('พนักงานขาย','Administrator','Trainner')","StaffPosition");
        var POS:Object ;            
        POS= GetStrDataResult.lastResult; 
    var savePosition:Array = new Array(POS.toString().split('|').length);
    var savePositionID:Array = new Array(POS.toString().split('|').length);
    var savePositionName:Array = new Array(POS.toString().split('|').length);
    var index:int;
    savePosition = POS.toString().split('|');
    for( index = 0; index < savePositionID.length; index++ )
            {
                savePositionID[index] = savePosition[index].split('^')[0];
            }

    for( index = 0; index < savePositionName.length; index++ )
            {
    savePositionName[index] = savePosition[index].split('^')[1];
    positionChoose.addItem(savePositionName[index]); 
            }
        }   
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:CallResponder id="GetStrDataResult"/>
    <service:Service id="service"
    fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n'+event.fault.faultDetail)"
                     showBusyCursor="true"/>

    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:DropDownList id="dropDownList" x="39" y="31" width="164"
                dataProvider="{positionChoose}"></s:DropDownList>
<s:Button id="btn1" x="132" y="64" label="Button"    
              click="btn1_clickHandler(event)"/>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

null is POS.How to POS is not null.

```
var POS:Object;         
POS = GetStrDataResult.lastResult; 
var savePosition:Array = new Array(POS.toString().split('|').length);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you are trying to do something with an object that is `null`.

The error message says the problem is on line 32. Using the code you have posted, that equates to a line that reads: `{`

But I am guessing the next line after that probably has the null object:

```
savePositionID[index] = savePosition[index].split('^')[0];
```

I'm guessing `savePosition[index]` is null.

You can set a break point here and confirm that in the debugger, trace the value, check for null explicitly, etc.

Answer (score 0):

May be the server is not returning any results for the query and hence the line

```
POS= GetStrDataResult.lastResult;
```

is having no effect. So when you basically say `POS.toString()` it throws the null pointer exception!